# Picard group of analytic variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

I am reading Huybrecht's introduction to complex geometry, and be stuck. First he introduces the exponential sheaf sequence, so that we have :
$H^1(X,Z)\to H^1(X,\mathcal{O}_X)\to H^1(X,\mathcal{O}^*_X)\to H^2(X,Z)$.

Then he says if $X$ is compact, then the map $H^1(X,Z)\to H^1(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ is injective. Why we have this?

Since $Pic(X)$ is isomorphic to $H^1(X,\mathcal{O}^*_X$), he says discrete part of $Pic(X)$ can be measured by it image in $H^2(X,Z)$ and continuous part comes from vector space $H^1(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$. Why $H^1(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ is  a vector space and what does he mean by discrete and continuous part?

I apologize if the question is very fundamental since I am totally new to complex geometry.

Comment: @Hoot just global sections?

Comment: @Hoot I know all holohorphic function is constant. You mean the map from global section of $\mathcal{O}_X$ to $\mathcal{O}_X^*$ is surjective? But why when X is not compact this is not true?

Comment: @Hoot I am sorry, I can not see. Actually I am even not sure about the definition of $\mathcal{O}_X$ here, I am just guessing it is non-vanishing holomorphic function. So could you please tell me why it is a counter example? Thanks.

Comment: Note that $H^0(\mathbb C^* , \mathbb O) \overset{e^{\cdot}}{\to} H^0(\mathbb C^*, \mathbb O)$ is not surjective: Consider the function $z \in H^0(\mathbb C^*, \mathbb O^*)$. There isn't a holmorphic function $f $  on $\mathbb C$ so that $e^f = z$, since that would implies $\log$ does not have a branch cut. @user330928

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's important to be aware of the whole long exact sequence. In general, you have an exact
\[
A \xrightarrow{u} B \to C \xrightarrow{w} D
\]
then $w$ is injective iff $u$ is surjective. So in your situation we can look at the map $H^0(X, \mathscr{O}) \to H^0(X, \mathscr{O}^*)$. Since $X$ is compact — and let me just assume connected — by the maximum principle this map on $H^0$ is just the old exponential $\mathbf C \to \mathbf C^*$.

For the second: the point is that each $\mathscr{O}(U)$ is a vector space, so all the $H^p(X, \mathscr{O})$ are vector spaces too. Maybe this is easiest to believe from the Čech point of view. I usually think of a vector space as a continuous thing — it's our local model for a manifold, after all. On the other hand, the $H^i(X,\mathbf{Z})$ are finitely generated abelian groups.

Comment: It is difficul too find a constructionor definition of $H^p(X,O_X)$ which does not make it clear that it is a vector space! (Using Yoneda extensions is one)